# Resize HTML content to get it fit in div and also need to maintain the aspect ration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a top bar in my application and we are creating the HTML content for top bar at server side so the HTML content i need to resize according to available space we have in top bar. below is my sample HTML

```
<p><strong><span style="color: #B8312F; font-size: 16px;">This is Title</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style="font-size: 9px;">123</span></strong></p>
```

This is the output I am currently having

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is put a `width:100%;` on the whole top bar div, and then in javascript resize it with the width of the element OR you can use the new CSS3 functionalities: vw and vh. So you can put you whole bar to `height:8vw;` and it will scale with your width as a ratio would do.

EDIT:
If you want to put the element in your topbar without resizing it, you can resize the element, putting the `font-size` of your text smaller or using `padding`/`margin`.

Comment: Actually I should not resize my top bar div i need to resize the HTML to get fit in top bar.

Comment: Okay, sorry for my missunderstood.
You can make a div that is going to contain the title and the 123.
And resize it to your top bar height

Comment: Thanks for understanding but still i am not clear like how to resize that div which will contain the html

Comment: I tried to use the margin/padding but that didn't worked. font-size is working but i need to know how to make whole html still look similar to what i have shown in screen shot (First line is having greater font size and second line having small font size)

Comment: <p><strong><span style="font-size: 9px;margin-top:-10px">123</span></strong></p> does not work ?